# Integrating $\arccos(f(x))$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate a function with respect to $x$ which is:
$$
\arccos(f(x)).
$$
I was wondering if there was a way to derive a general formula for this (and, if possible for the other inverse trig functions too).

If not, then specifically, I was trying to integrate (where $d>0$ is a constant):

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi d}\int_0^d \arccos\bigl(1-2(d^2-x^2)/d^2\bigr)+\arccos\bigl(1-2x(2d-x)/d^2\bigr)\,dx.
$$

The answer should be 
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}, 
$$
but I'd rather be able to prove it analytically.

[On wolfram alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtQne.png)

Comment: For arbitrary functions, elementary closed form solutions to antiderivatives of such are unlikely to exist. Perhaps some definite integrals can be expressed in closed form, but that's still unlikely.

Comment: I edited your question a bit. Please check that I did not change anything important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no general formula. In the specific case, it "miraculously" works out, though.

First, we note that if we let $u=d-x$ in
$$
\arccos\bigl(1-2x(2d-x)/d^2\bigr)
$$
we get
$$
\arccos\bigl(1-2(d^2-u^2)/d^2\bigr)
$$
so your integral equals
$$
\frac{1}{\pi d}\int_0^d \arccos\bigl(1-2(d^2-x^2)/d^2\bigr)\,dx
$$
To find a primitive, we integrate by parts
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^d \frac{1}{\pi d}\arccos\bigl(1-2(d^2-x^2)/d^2\bigr)\,dx&=\Bigl[\frac{x}{\pi d}\arccos\bigl(1-2(d^2-x^2)/d^2\bigr)\Bigr]_0^d\\
&\quad+\frac{2}{\pi d}\int_0^d \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2(d^2-x^2)}}\,dx
\end{aligned}
$$
I leave you with the last integral to practice on. It has a very simple form. Ask if you need help on it.